# facing issues in developing a multipage registration form using Node , express and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing a 3 page registration form and storing data using mongodb.
But due to multiple pages, i created the collection "detail" outside of all the post requests of all the 3 pages. But Now it always stores only one data. it shows only one user with the recent details. please tell me a way to store every user details.
I know that i have to make all the fields equal to NULL but when in the last i did this(first saved and then made fields equal to null), then in my database I got null values only. Please help me.

```
const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express( );

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/detailsdb", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const detailsSchema = {
  Name: String,
  Divorce_id: String,
  Date_of_Birth: String,
  Nationality: String,
  Marital_Status: String,
  Highest_Education: String
};

const Detail = mongoose.model("Detail", detailsSchema);


const detail = new Detail({
  Name: null,
  Divorce_id: null,
  Date_of_Birth: null,
  Nationality: null,
  Marital_Status: null,
  Highest_Education: null

});


 
app.get("/FORM-1",function(req,res)
{
  
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/form1.html");

});



app.get("/FORM-2",function(req,res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/form2.html");
});



app.get("/FORM-3",function(req,res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/form3.html");
});



app.post("/FORM-1", function(req, res){
  detail.Name = req.body.name;
  detail.Divorce_id = req.body.id;

  res.redirect("/FORM-2");
});

app.post("/FORM-2", function(req, res){

  
    detail.Date_of_Birth =  req.body.dob;
    detail.Nationality = req.body.nationality;

    res.redirect("/FORM-3");

});


app.post("/FORM-3", function(req, res){
  
    detail.Marital_Status= req.body.marital_status;
    detail.Highest_Education=  req.body.highest_education;
    
    detail.save();

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: use default value for the fields in the schma

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I have set to null. what you want me to do?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi yes, but it only saves on user details, i mean it changes the name etc to the recent details.

Comment: put the console.log in the all post routes like the console.log(1) and (2) and (3), when you call first post, running all post request

Comment: Hi, I would advise you to handle the multi-form part in the frontend using Javascript, and then sending all the data at once.

You application's architecture is prone to fail because you are creating an instance of  `Detail` on application startup, and then you are setting values to it, as soon as multiple users start submitting in parallel your application will have inconsistencies in data: data from two users being mixed up.

Comment: @FirminoChangan  i am a beginner i dont know much about how things work. Can you plz give more idea how to do it.

Comment: @meenu, if I was in your position, I would create just one view `form` that would enable the user see multiple steps (multi-step form), once in the last step of the form (let's say step 3), if the data inserted is right, then your app would submit the whole data to your backend. This would simplify quite significantly the logic in your backend. 

Also take a look at the comment from THEBIGK V. `new Detail` should be instantiated inside `app.post("", (req, res) => {});`

Answer (score 2):

The approach is very wrong here,

1. `detail` is being a global object. updates coming for any request would be saved in ambigous order.
2. details saved in `FORM_1`'s POST request must be saved and it's documentId `_id` must be returned to the form for subsequent requests made to `FORM_2` and `FORM_3` to make the update and not save.
3. if you're updating any field with `null` it'll actually be saved as null, not like it'll not get updated.

**Suggestions:**

in FORM_1

```
app.post("/FORM-1", function(req, res){
  let detail = new Detail({
          Name: req.body.name,
          Divorce_id: req.body.id;,
          Date_of_Birth: null,
          Nationality: null,
          Marital_Status: null,
          Highest_Education: null
         });
  detail.save(function(err,savedDetail){
      if(!err)
      res.json({savedDetail});
  })
  
  //res.redirect("/FORM-2");
});
```

in FORM_2

```
app.post("/FORM-2", function(req, res){
       let updateDetails = {
               Date_of_Birth : req.body.dob,
               Nationality : req.body.nationality
        };
Detail.findOneAndUpdate({
_id : req.body._id
},{
  $set : updateDetails
},function(err,data){
if(!err){
res.redirect("/Form-3");
}
});
    
    //detail.Date_of_Birth =  req.body.dob;
    //detail.Nationality = req.body.nationality;

    //res.redirect("/FORM-3");

});
```

in Form_3

```
app.post("/FORM-3", function(req, res){
  let updateDetails = {
                   Marital_Status : req.body.marital_status,
                   Highest_Education : req.body.highest_education
            };
    //detail.Marital_Status= req.body.marital_status;
    //detail.Highest_Education=  req.body.highest_education; 
Detail.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id : req.body._id
    },{
      $set : updateDetails
    },function(err,data){
    if(!err){
    res.json({updated : true});
    }
    });
    //detail.save();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for this. I am facing errors by doing this. Well, first two fields in form1 are saving but other fields always have null in them. What to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Detail must be initialized in the `FORM_1`'s POST request

and then sent immediately to the database using `detail.save()`;

and then you must get the above created document's id and pass it to the `FORM_2` and perform a update operation on the object on the next post request for `FORM_2`

and likewise for `FORM_3`

Comment: Thankyou very much for this. I am facing errors by doing this. Well, first two fields in form1 are saving but other fields always have null in them. What to do.

Comment: for that you need to deep dive into defining schemas, 
here's an example  for setting a default name : 
const detailsSchema = {
  Name: { type : String, default : ""}
  Divorce_id: String,
  Date_of_Birth: String,
  Nationality: String,
  Marital_Status: String,
  Highest_Education: String
};

Comment: @AnkittSharma I am still getting null in all the fileds exceptthe fields of first page.please help.